# Editing elements of a numpy vector via a for-loop

Tags: arrays, numpy, loops, if-statement, vector

I seem to lack basic understanding of numpy vectors… I tried to edit the elements inside a numpy vector, yet I couldn't figure out what the problem with it is.
I specifically look for an answer regarding numpy vectors. Ty in advance. :)

This is my try so far.

```
list1 =[2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0]
list2 = [3.0, 6.0, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2.0]

vec1 = np.array(list1)
vec2 = np.array(list2)

vec3 = vec1-vec2
print(vec3)

# 3a)
hamming=np.zeros(6)

for x in vec3:
    for i in range(len(vec3)):
        if x == 0.0:
            hamming[i] = 1.0
        else:
            hamming[i] = 0.0
print(hamming)
```

The response I am getting is

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

and should be

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be aware that you have two loops and `hamming` will have the values from the last iteration in the outer loop. Therefore, when x=0 which is the last value in`vec3`, all hamming values will be ones because x is always 0 during the last iteration.

**Solution**, you can follow:

```
for i,x in enumerate(vec3):
    if x == 0.0:
      hamming[i] = 1.0
    else:
      hamming[i] = 0.0
print(hamming)
```

**Output**: `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]`